# Script for filing call recordings into date folders

Tags: bash

We have an IP PBX that is running Asterisk and is set by the manufacturer to delete call recordings after a certain time period. I am backing these up to an Ubuntu server using rsync so that we are able to store them indefinitely.

The issue that I have is that all of the recordings are all placed into a single directory. Conveniently the files are named in the same structure:

> year.month.day.hour.min.sec-callref-extension-callerid.wav

What I would like to do is set up a directory structure that would be Year/Month/Day (with the month being correctly ordered), then move each  of the files into the corresponding order.

Personal note: I am confident at working with Ubuntu at the command line but don't have experience of running or automating scripts so advice is greatly welcomed. (Happy to learn!) Thanks in advance.

---

The script that was supplied earlier is working great.  I have come upto a further slight issue.

I am using a crontab to rsync IPPBX to Ubuntu Server, then another to file these recordings using the script below.
Each evening the rsync is re-downloading all the recordings as it thinks that the destination folder is empty.

I have two questions:
Can the rsync be incorporated into the script below so that one a single file is used?
Can the script understand what has already been downloaded so that it is only downloading new files?

Answer (score 3):

That's actually fairly simple with bash. Just iterate the files, extract the year, month and day, then move it accordingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# iterate all the wav-files that has at least 3 dots in addition to the extension
for file in *.*.*.*.wav; do

    # In the case of no files matching the glob, file will contain the glob itself
    # which will make the mkdir later on create './*/*/*'. Avoid that by testing
    # if file contains an existing file.
    [[ -e $file ]] || continue

    # split out year month and day from the filename
    IFS=. read -r year month day _ <<< "$file"

    # make sure the directories exist, then move it
    mkdir -p "./$year/$month/$day" &&
    mv "./$file" "./$year/$month/$day"
done
```

Comment: Geriha,Thanks for the script. How do I specify which folder to run this script against? Or do I run it in the original folder that the files are in?

Comment: @BatchHeader, same dir as the files, yes. Save the script somewhere in PATH, e.g. `~/bin/filerecs` or `/usr/local/bin/filerecs` and make it executable `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/filerecs`. To use it, change to the right directory `cd /path/to/recordings`, then run `filerecs`.